# How to generate an A-2 PDF

Tags: c#, pdf

I am trying to create an A-2 ODF with iText 7 but I am getting this exception:

> iText.Pdfa.PdfA Conformance Exception: 'All the fonts must be
> embedded. This one is not: Times-Bold '.

If anyone can help me I would greatly appreciate it.

My code is this:

```
iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter writer = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter (pdfNewName);

ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties ();

iText.Pdfa.PdfADocument pdf = new iText.Pdfa.PdfADocument (writer, iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_2B, new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfOutputIntent ("Custom", "", 6-2) ", new FileStream (profile, FileMode.Open)));

iText.Layout.Document document = new iText.Layout.Document (pdf);

iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFont ExternalSource = iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFontFactory.CreateFont (bold, iText.IO.Font.PdfEncodings.WINANSI);

iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph p = new iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph ();

p.SetFont (externalSource);

document.Add (p);

HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf (htmlString, pdf, properties);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the documentation of PdfFontFactory? Several of its methods take an argument specifying whether or not the font should be embedded. Such as this one:

```
iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFontFactory.CreateRegisteredFont   (   String  fontName,
   String   encoding,
   bool     embedded 
)
```

If you want to generate a PDF/A file, all fonts *must* be embedded, even standard 14 fonts such as Times. So you'll have to tell iText to embed the font you want it to use for your text.

Comment: I already entered the Times Roman font but I still get the same error, this is my code

iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFont ExternalSource = iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFontFactory.CreateFont (timesRoman, iText.IO.Font.PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true); iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph p = new iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph ();
p.SetFont (externalSource);
document.Add (p);

HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf (htmlString, pdf, properties);